# Как правильно использовать SSL_read при условии неблокируемого сокета

Tags: c++, winapi, openssl

В мануале написано
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_read.html

C++ (Qt)Выделить код
1

> If the underlying BIO is non-blocking, SSL_read() will also return
>   when the underlying BIO could not satisfy the needs of SSL_read() to
>   continue the operation. In this case a call to SSL_get_error(3) with
>   the return value of SSL_read() will yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ or
>   SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE. As at any time a re-negotiation is possible, a
>   call to SSL_read() can also cause write operations!

что при неблокируемом сокете будут возникать ошибки, мол он не смог считать так как не успели придти данные или они пришли но в недостаточном количестве для расшифровки. Если такая ошибка выявлена то функцию SSL_read() нужно вызывать заново.

И в конечном итоге картина выглядит примерно следующим образом

```
    bool waitForReadyRead(){
    if(lp_current_conection == nullptr){
        return 0;
    }
    ResetEvent(hEventRead);
    if(WSAEventSelect(lp_current_conection->handleSocket,  hEventRead,  FD_READ )){
        return 0;
    }

    tempDRORD = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(2, hEvents, false, DWORD(ReadWriteTimeout*1000), true );

    if(WSAEventSelect(lp_current_conection->handleSocket,  hEventRead,  0 )){
        return 0;
    }
    if ((tempDRORD == WSA_WAIT_FAILED) || (tempDRORD == WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT)){
        return 0;
    }
    if(tempDRORD == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(tempDRORD == 1){
        ResetEvent(hEventStop);
    }
    return 0;

}
bool RecvDataHttp(QByteArray& data){

 for(int z = 0;z<1000;z++){
        ZeroMemory(mRecvData,SizeRequest);

        if (!waitForReadyRead()) // select
        {
          lp_current_conection->changeSocketState(BLOCKED_SOCKET);
          return 0;
        }

            size_recv = SSL_read(lp_current_conection->lp_ssl,  mRecvData, SizeRequest-1);
            if(size_recv <= 0){
                size_recv = SSL_get_error(lp_current_conection->lp_ssl, size_recv);
                if(size_recv == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ){


                    count_cycle++;
                    qDebug()<<"count_cycle = "<<count_cycle;
                    ResetEvent(hEventStop);
                    WaitForSingleObject(hEventStop,DWORD(10*count_cycle));
                    ResetEvent(hEventStop);
                    continue;

                }else if(size_recv == SSL_ERROR_NONE){
                    break;
                }else{
                    if(!lp_current_conection->changeSocketState(BLOCKED_SOCKET)){
                        return 0;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            data.append(mRecvData,size_recv);

        // тут кусок кода который согласно http протоколу определяет все ли считано и выходит из функции.
```

Но при таком варианте есть 2 проблемы:

1) select в данном случае абсолютно бесполезен, так как даже если данные для считывания есть, то SSL_read() все равно может возвращать ошибку SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, так как имеющихся данных ему может не хватить.
2) При условии медленного интернета или медленного сайта, на открытие одной страницы количество срабатываний continue; может доходить до 100,200 и более итераций, что весьма неплохо грузит процессор.

Единственный выход который я нашел это сделать перед continue; слип на 10 миллисекунд, но уверен что такая реализация равносильна идиотизму, подскажите как реализовать чтение правильно? нигде в гугле нормального примера не нашел.

Comment: Вы тут что-то странное делаете. Зачем там неблокирующий сокет, когда функция чтения данных `RecvDataHttp` имеет типичный блокирующий интерфейс? Зачем функция `waitForReadyRead`, ведущая себя подобно `select`, когда из сокета можно читать не дожидаясь появления в нем данных? Имеет смысл переделать `RecvDataHttp` чтобы она принимала на вход делегат, который надо будет вызвать, когда станут доступны какие-нибудь дешифрованные данные, а чтение из сокета переделать чтобы они принимало делегат, который надо будет вызвать при получении данных для скармливания их в SSL.

Comment: 1) Неблокирующий соект нужен по той причине что функция SSL_recv при условии блокирующего сокета имеет возможность зависать намертво. waitForReadyRead нужна для того чтобы цикл чтения не делал миллон оборотов на чтение страницы сайта.
2) Каким образом мне понять что мне доступны данные для дешифрования?

Comment: Ну если цель состоит только в том, чтобы `SSL_recv` не блокировалась намертво, то и такой вариант сойдет. Только от `for(int z = 0;z<1000;z++){` избавиться и все.

Comment: Смысл избавляться от цикла? мне надо всю страницу сайта считать, а не только заголовки.